# jquery draggable/droppable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

Any help with the following will be much appreciated. I need to have a picture outside a droppable box. The user should be able to drag the picture to the box and once the picture is inside the box, the user should still be able to drag it, but only inside of the box.

Thank you in advance for any pointers.

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far that just supports the dragging it inside a droppable box? If you'd like help doing that first half, let us know and we can help you out. But if you post that half of your code, then we can append what is necessary to support the subsequent contained draggable. You can use [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to share with us. Welcome to SO!

Comment: Thank you. Here is an draggable/droppable example from the web that I have modified. http://jsfiddle.net/sPdwm/

Comment: I added $( "#draggable" ).draggable({containment:"#droppable"}); to the drop: function and was able to contain the movement of the picture, I updated the code and seems to work ok.

Comment: here is the updated code http://jsfiddle.net/sPdwm/1/

Comment: Ok, I added the code in your example as the answer (for future reference).

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by adding the "containment" option to the draggable object in the droppable object's "drop" callback.  For example:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
    $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $( this )
                .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
                .find( "p" )
                .html( "Dropped!" );
            $( "#draggable" ).draggable({containment:"#droppable"});
        }  });
});
```

In the option above, once the item is actually dropped, the drop callback fires and causes the draggable item to be constrained to the item in the "containment" option.